# Video or iframe tag not working properly when binding it's src

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a website where I'm binding the video or iframe tag to the youtube link I'm getting from API. It only works properly when I'm not binding the link.

This is how it is looking [image]

This is what i want [image]
I'm using vuejs 2.

This is the code I have. I'm looping over the data I'm getting from API. This code is working fine if I'm using the link directly in src without binding it's value.

```html
<div
    class="gallery-hover-wrap"
    data-aos="fade-up"
    v-for="(item, index) in gallerydata"
    :key="index"
>
    <img
      v-if="item.image"
      :src="item.image"
      style="width: 100%"
      @click="OpenGalleryPopFun(item)"
      class="itemimg"
    />
    <div v-if="item.video_link">
      <iframe :src="item.video_link" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
      <!-- <video
        no-controls=""
        muted="muted"
        autoplay="autoplay"
        loop="loop"
      >
        <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YklfuduwIGk" type="video/mp4" />
      </video> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a complete question?

Comment: please provide sample code

Comment: It's the first time I'm asking the question on stack overflow. please ignore if any mistakes from my side. I have added the template from my code  @Meow

Answer (score 2):

From the look of your image, it seems that your video url are broken.

Instead of using `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YklfuduwIGk` try using an embed link `https://www.youtube.com/embed/YklfuduwIGk`

This might fix your issue.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks, man!!. From the backend itself, I was getting the broken link which I didn't know that this is broken. Now using embed link. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<video :key="item.video_link" no-controls="" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source :src="item.video_link" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. "Try this" and a piece of example code isn't really a helpful, complete answer. Can you provide some explanation to accompany your solution?

Comment: @Devi Didn't work